# How to change row style/class by clicking button in ag-grid?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

Is  there any way to make row change background by clicking on button? I have the following code:

```
rowClassRules: {
    "a-grade": params => params.api.getValue("Grade", params.node) == 'A',
    "b-grade": params => params.api.getValue("Grade", params.node) == 'B',
    "c-grade": params => params.api.getValue("Grade", params.node) == 'C',
    
  },
```

It changes row color based on value in the column Grade. But I want to do the same only after pressing a button, and also other button should turn it off (like Turn On/Off highlighting). I have no idea how to turn this code into a function which I can use in the button's onclick.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have actions like mouse-click in ag-grid you should use a component renderer:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/component-cell-renderer/

There you can set a hidden property like 'isHighlighting' in row data using params.api with any proper method like: setData(), applyTransaction(), or applyTransactionAsync().

Also, consider using a simpler way to write your rowClassRules:

https://ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/row-styles/#row-class-rules

The final code should be something like this:

```
rowClassRules: {
    'a-grade': function(params) { return params.data.isHighlighting && params.data.Grade === 'A'; },
    'b-grade': function(params) { return params.data.isHighlighting && params.data.Grade === 'B'; },
    'c-grade': function(params) { return params.data.isHighlighting && params.data.Grade === 'C'; }
};
```

If the button is not inside the grid you can use this code:

```
isHighlighting = false;

onClick() {
   isHighlighting  = !isHighlighting;
   gridApi.redrawRows();
}
```

and

```
'a-grade': function(params) { return isHighlighting && params.data.Grade === 'A'; }
```

Comment: This code deosn't work for me :( Just nothing happens without any mistakes in console.

I don't need necessarily to click inside ag-grid, I can make a button in HTML above like "Press to Highlight". But I don't know how to make a highlighting function applying CSS styles to connect with onclick.

Comment: The answer above looks legitimate, not sure why it's not working on your machine.

I don't know if it's relevant to you, but I've only been using AG Grid with Adaptable for a few years now.
It saves me from such implementation details and from solutions which often are brittle and break on AG Grid updates.

For your specific use case, Adaptable has the concept of Conditional Styles, see https://docs.adaptabletools.com/guide/handbook-conditional-styling